# Sitecore package installation

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to install a Sitecore package. The installation fails with following error:

The installation failed for the following reason:
**path is not under the root**

Please help. Is any problem with the package or, with the target instance where I am installing?

**Following exception in the log:**

Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: The directory name e:\inetpub\wwwroot\project20\website\project.webui\sitecore\shell\override is invalid.
Source: System
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_Path(String value)
at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.InitFolderWatcher(Boolean deep)
at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource..ctor(String namespace, String prefix, String folder, Boolean deep)
at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlSourceFactory.CreateControlSource(XmlNode configNode)
at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.ControlFactory.ReadControlSources()

Comment: I think the package is trying to create items under a not existing path, I suggest you compare the items path in the package with your content tree, You can unzip the package and check the items folder.

Comment: Could not extract the package. error: "compressed zip file is invalid". but it did not give any issues while creating the package from the source environment.:(

Comment: You should be able to unzip the package, try to copy the package to C:\ and extract it there.

Comment: No luck. tried copying to c:\ and extract. also tried creating fresh package from source instance.

Comment: Can you check if the parent of the root item in your package exist in the target content tree, Also can you check sitecore log files, usually you can find the ID of the item that produce the issue.

I had a similar issue before and the problem that the name of the item was long for the new environment.

Comment: could not find much specific about this in the log. the last logged exception is updated in the question.

Comment: and yes.. I have some items with longer names in the package that I am trying to install..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125344/discussion-between-naresh-sadu-and-mohammed-syam).

Comment: Have you set your permissions up correctly in your web root? Ensure NETWORK SERVICE has write access and your App Pool is using NEWORK SERVICE.

Comment: Also check your data folder is the same.

Comment: Check if you have /Data/packages/ folder under your site.

Comment: Yes.. access rights are correctly set. I am able to install other packages properly.. problem is only with this particular one...

Comment: yes, packages folder is present and has full access.

Comment: Was able to install after changing following setting <setting name="Serialization.SerializationFolderPathMaxLength" value="90" /> to <setting name="Serialization.SerializationFolderPathMaxLength" value="50" /> as found in another blog.. https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn/issues/34 .. but still not sure what the issue was